# Extract heading and paragraphs of a docx-file

Tags: php, regex, xml-parsing, docx

I need to read a docx-file to get i.e. the headings and the content of the document in variables.
I'm reading the file like this:

```
function read_file_docx($filename){
    if(!$filename || !file_exists($filename)) return false;
    $zip = zip_open($filename);
    if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;

    while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {
        if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;
        if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;
        $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
        zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
    }
    zip_close($zip);

    //$striped_content = strip_tags($content);

    return $striped_content;
}
```

My problem is how to get i.e. all heading1, heading2 and heading 3 and the content of those parts in a array for further processing.

Comment: Rather than try to write it all yourself, why not use a library like [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) that has already been written... and don't even consider regexps for this

Comment: "With PHPWord, you can create DOCX, ODT, or RTF documents dynamically using your PHP 5.3+ scripts". But I need it the other way round. I need a HTML-code from the docx. Just heading, paragraph and maybe bold and italic. Nothing more.

Comment: `PHPWord is a library written in pure PHP that provides a set of classes to write to and read from different document file formats. The current version of PHPWord supports Microsoft Office Open XML (OOXML or OpenXML), OASIS Open Document Format for Office Applications (OpenDocument or ODF), Rich Text Format (RTF), HTML, and PDF.`.... I spy HTML in that list

Comment: Of course, if you want to write it all yourself, feel free..... it's a pretty major project even if all you want is `Just heading, paragraph and maybe bold and italic. Nothing more`. The very fact that you were asking here suggested that you were looking for a solution, so I suggested one..... but if all you want is to write it yourself, then go ahead

Comment: Of course I'm searching for a solution. I will give that a try. Thanks.